# in Async Task : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog, android-logcat

**What i want**

When click on Marker in Map, Show alert dialog with list view (containing text)

**LogCat Error**

```
05-01 23:20:21.098 11392-11654/com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
05-01 23:20:21.099 11392-11654/com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject W/System.err:     at com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject.MainActivity$override.retreive_message(MainActivity.java:372)
05-01 23:20:21.099 11392-11654/com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject W/System.err:     at com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
05-01 23:20:21.099 11392-11654/com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject W/System.err:     at com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject.MainActivity.retreive_message(MainActivity.java:0)
05-01 23:20:21.099 11392-11654/com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject W/System.err:     at com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject.MainActivity$GetAtms.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:300)
05-01 23:20:21.099 11392-11654/com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject W/System.err:     at com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject.MainActivity$GetAtms.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:257)
05-01 23:20:21.099 11392-11654/com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-01 23:20:21.099 11392-11654/com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-01 23:20:21.099 11392-11654/com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-01 23:20:21.099 11392-11654/com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-01 23:20:21.099 11392-11654/com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-01 23:20:21.099 11392-11654/com.example.talha.atmlocaterproject W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

What i am doing is in OnMarkerClick() is calling AsyncTask to get message from cloud.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    String atm_title = marker.getTitle();
    option = "retreive_message";
    new GetAtms(atm_title).execute();      //here is the call to asyncTask
    return false;
}
```

Now in doInBackground() method , i retreive the message from cloud and set adapter

```
DBCollection c5  = db.getCollection("ATM_message");
    String[] atm_message = new String[50];
    try{
        Log.d("retreive message","before lopping");
        DBCursor cursor = c5.find();
        String atm_title,message,username;
        int message_adding_counter = 0;
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject doc = cursor.next();
            atm_title = "" + doc.get("atm_name");
            message = "" + doc.get("message");
            username ="" + doc.get("username");
            Log.d("retreive message","between lopping");

            if(atm_title.equalsIgnoreCase(title)){
                atm_message[message_adding_counter]=message;
                Log.d("retreive message"," adding message");

            }
        }
        Log.d("retreive message","" + atm_message[0]);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.textView,atm_message);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        showDailogListView(listview);
```

**showDailogListView()**

```
public void showDailogListView(View view){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
    builder.setView(view);
    AlertDialog dailog = builder.create();
    dailog.show();
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**OnCreate()**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mProgressDialog= new ProgressDialog(this);

    try {
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `onPostExecute` to deal with your UI:

Change your signature of AsyncTask:

```
public class GetAtms extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    public GetAtms(String title, ArrayAdapter<String> adapter)
    {
        mAdapter = adapter;
        //the rest of the constructor codes
    }

    //rest of your code
```

let your `doInBackground` return the result String array to `onPostExecute`

```
DBCollection c5  = db.getCollection("ATM_message");
String[] atm_message = new String[50];
try{
    Log.d("retreive message","before lopping");
    DBCursor cursor = c5.find();
    String atm_title,message,username;
    int message_adding_counter = 0;
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject doc = cursor.next();
        atm_title = "" + doc.get("atm_name");
        message = "" + doc.get("message");
        username ="" + doc.get("username");
        Log.d("retreive message","between lopping");

        if(atm_title.equalsIgnoreCase(title)){
            atm_message[message_adding_counter]=message;
            Log.d("retreive message"," adding message");

        }
    }
    Log.d("retreive message","" + atm_message[0]);

    return atm_message;
```

in `onPostExecute` do:

```
public void onPostExecute(String[] data)
{
    mAdapter.clear();
    mAdapter.addAll(data);
}
```

and finally change your onMarkerClick:

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    String atm_title = marker.getTitle();
    option = "retreive_message";
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(...) //your listview resource
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.textView,null);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    new GetAtms(atm_title,adapter).execute();      //here is the call to asyncTask
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to return array adapter from doInBackground method and set progress dialog in onPreExecute method;

```
doInBackground(){
//your code
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.textView,atm_message);
return adapter;
}

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayAdapter<String> result) {
      return result;
    }
```

//////////////

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    String atm_title = marker.getTitle();
    option = "retreive_message";
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=(new GetAtms(atm_title)).execute();      
   listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u facing null object reference please first see that all textview are properly findviewbyid done and secondly whatever adapter you are setting please do it in postexecute method ,it will work try it.